# How to add a cipher suite to Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

For some reason, I had to use an older version of the Chrome browser (e.g. Chrome 50), but in fact, Chrome 50 couldn't open some pages because the cipher suite they used was not supported in Chrome 50, like TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030) and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f) and so on.

Because of this, I am getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH errors when I use Chrome50 to access certain websites that contain a specific cipher suite. In fact, those sites use tls1.2. The ssllabs browser test shows that my browser supports tls1.2, but this test also tells me that my browser does not support cipher suites such as TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030).

How do I manually add these cipher suites to my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I manually add these cipher suites to my browser?

Chrome 50 already supports `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, but there appears to have been a bug, which was fixed with Chrome 51.  The solution to your problem is to upgrade your Chrome to a newer version.  Based on when [Intent to Ship: AES_256_GCM in TLS.](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/security-dev/5BmCy4Gx3gs/1FiAx2YpGgAJ) was published, which happened before Chrome 50 was released, evidence supports that Chrome 50 supports the cipher you want to use.

[image]

[Support AES-256-GCM](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608887)

While Chrome 50 appears to support `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`, support for it was removed in later versions, and likely suffers from the same bug as the other cipher.

[image]

[Relevant Bug Report - Enable AES_256_GCM in TLS.](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591516)

[Enable AES_256_GCM ciphers.](https://codereview.chromium.org/1769393002)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved this problem after upgrading Chrome to 51.